# CoreBluetooth stopadvertising does not stop

Tags: ios, bluetooth

I have an iOS app that uses CoreBluetooth.

It is able to advertise and be connected too just fine.

When I call stopAdvertising on the peripheral manager object, it doesn't stop advertising. I waited for about 10 minutes and it still shows up in my bluetooth le scanner and I can still connect to it.

My iPhone is an iPhone X with the latest software.

I get no errors that I can detect and isAdvertising stays true.

Anyone know why it won't stop advertising?

Comment: Please edit your question to show relevant code, but at a guess you are not calling `stopAdvertising` on the right instance of `CBPeripheralManager`

Comment: Well, I am not sure what is going on now. I put in debug code to NSLog the peripheral manager object and ran some tests and it does seem to stop advertising in my simple testing. It looks like it might have something to do with connecting / disconnecting. I did verify that the same peripheral manager object is the one I am calling the stop advertising on. I will do some more testing and get back to this post when I have more information.

Comment: I've seen the same thing.  Did you ever find an answer?  I'm testing between an iPhone 7 and a Xr.

Comment: Also noticed that if you restart the phone, fixes itself temporarily.  I can startAdvertising and stopAdvertising as expected.  But eventually, the issue returns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience with GATT on iOS, I notice that after calling `stopAdvertising` method I have to call `removeAllServices` method too (it remove just your services as mentioned in official docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheralmanager/1393269-removeallservices?language=objc)).

But, if there are any clients scanning my GATT server or connected to it, I have to wait that they stop watching it to be not discoverable anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar experience where starting and stopping the advertising works just fine when the app is in foreground. In order to experience problems I need to do the following:

1. while in foreground start the advertising
2. put the app in background
3. put the app in foreground

At this point the advertisement package looks like this:

```
{
    kCBAdvDataHashedServiceUUIDs =     (
        <my service UUID>
    );
    kCBAdvDataIsConnectable = 1;
    kCBAdvDataRxPrimaryPHY = 0;
    kCBAdvDataRxSecondaryPHY = 0;
    kCBAdvDataServiceUUIDs =     (
        <my service UUID>
    );
    kCBAdvDataTimestamp = "617105621.560463";
    kCBAdvDataTxPowerLevel = 12;
}
```

where the `kCBAdvDataHashedServiceUUIDs` string is the `CBAdvertisementDataOverflowServiceUUIDsKey` constant. So the advertisement package contains the advertised service UUID in both the service and overflow area.
At this point, if I stop advertising, the advertisement package becomes like the one in background (the same that I observe after step 2)

```
{
    kCBAdvDataHashedServiceUUIDs =     (
        <my service UUID>
    );
    kCBAdvDataIsConnectable = 1;
    kCBAdvDataRxPrimaryPHY = 0;
    kCBAdvDataRxSecondaryPHY = 0;
    kCBAdvDataTimestamp = "617105621.560463";
    kCBAdvDataTxPowerLevel = 12;
}
```

At this point an iOS app scanning for my UUID will receive notifications via the `centralManager:didDiscoverPeripheral:advertisementData:RSSI:` callback method.

I do experience the same also if I kill the advertising app, while it is advertising.

few notes:

- `isAdvertising` reports the correct value (so when I stop the advertising it reports NO even if there is the issue I just described)
- I tried some cleanup like the one suggested by Darion Badlydone
- Deactivating and activating the bluetooth from the settings fixes the advertising

Answer (score 0):

well, this issue has been discussed a lot. I also reported this to Apple as a bug, but they seem not to be actively change that.
The cause of this issue is that all the applications in your iphone shares the same overflowserviceuuid area, including the default bluetooth in your iphone's settings. That means if your app override the overflow area in GATT stack(by moving to the background), this uuid will take effective even you kill your app, because your default bluetooth is still working by using this shared overflow area, that is why other phones will can find you.
Also, there are few workarounds to fix this, depends on the business scenarios.

Comment: So, what are those workarounds? An analysis of the problem background is interesting but not a (complete) solution.

Comment: I have one almost the complete solution aross with Android and iOS devices, even with the wearables, but with the following limitations: 1. Battery consumption 2. Appstore audit 3. You can do contact tracing in background but you can't switch on/off the function automatically since iOS14. Simply you can just advertise a new special service to override the overflow again.

Comment: You can [edit] your answer to improve it, don't put that kind of information in a comment. However, the goal of answering here is to *help others solve the problem*. Please write an answer only if you can actually share something more concrete.

Answer (score 0):

You can not stop the advertising is because you ever put your application into background status, which will override the overflow area. Even you call stopAdvertising it will stop the foreground advertising. However, as I said, since all the applications shared the same overflow area, this area will keep advertising (BY default bluetooth of settings). To kill this, when you call stopadvertising, you have to override GATT stack again by using another meaningless uuid like 0001.